# Expire login session after some time in android

Tags: android

I need to implement auto log out functionality in my android application , no matter which screen is showing currently.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save login time in shared pref. Set logout time. Check `currentTime != logoutTime` by alarm manager. If return true show dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set one alarm manager after `login` then whenever that alarm will trigger then call one `broadcast reciver` and in that `broadcast` just write code for log out and `clear all session value` which related to that `login`

u can restart your app like this and from this all previews activity all top will be also clear

```
Intent i = cntxt.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(cntxt.getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
cntxt.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Ok, then how the current visible activity will finish from broadcast receiver.

Comment: just remove all contact off your app and restart it from that reciver itself dude its very easy

Comment: actually i already done this in my last app so i have knowledge about it

Comment: Can you please share the whole broadcast receiver code

Comment: is this code works if app is not opened? I mean user logged in and killed the app before session expire.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would create [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and then `AlarmManager` in it.

```
public class AutoLogOutService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setAlarm(0, 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent == null) {
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if ("action_log_out".equals(intentAction)) {
            logOut();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void setAlarm(long startAt, long ulogOutPeriod) {
        final Context context = getBaseContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AutoLogOutService.class);
        intent.setAction("action_log_out");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC,
                startAt,
                updatePeriod,
                pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

Also to start it with Device boot I would register boot `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, PlanetsService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

In your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name="yourpackage.BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Usually session data is stored in `SharedPreferences`. I wrote a little article about them, you can find it [here](http://yakivmospan.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/best-practice-sharedpreferences/)

Answer (score 0):

For Automatic Session Expire :

**Use a static data member that represents your token and the time it was validated. Check the token in onResume() of each activity. If the token is missing or is out of date, redirect the user to the login activity.**

For Logout Manually :

```
public void logout(View view){
      SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences
      (MainActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
      editor.clear();
      editor.commit();
      moveTaskToBack(true); 
      Welcome.this.finish();
```

Here is the tutorialspoint guide to you

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_session_management.htm